# (iOS) Cancelling all local notifications when app is no longer running

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm working on an app that is too complex to fully explain, so to support my question I will provide a very basic example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Say I have an app that shows a timer of 10 minutes. If a button is pressed, the timer runs down to 0. When the app is closed (not terminated), I want to notify the user of this by a local notification.

When the app gets terminated, the timer obviously stops as well. However, the local notification would still be set up and fired eventually.

I don't want this to happen. I only want to show the notification if the app is still running in the background. If the app gets terminated by the user or by a crash, the notification should not appear.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance guys.

Laurens

Comment: If the user terminates your app by swiping it away, your app doesn’t get a chance to execute any code.

Comment: I don't think so, because you don't get the event that the app is force closed.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the state of your app where you setup and show your local notification:

**Swift 3**

```
let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
if state == .background {
    print("App in Background")
}
```

Comment: Ok, but if he sets up the local notification when he’s sure the app state is in background this will not solve the problem? When the timer ends and call the method if the app state is in background the local notification will be scheduled, or I’m wrong?! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro I think you're right! You can get the result by checking app's state while scheduling a new notification.

Comment: Hi Francesco, thanks for your reply. The problem is that the notification that I want to set up gets scheduled 10 minutes in advance, not when the timer ends. At the time of scheduling the notification, the app is always active and visible. If, in the meanwhile, the app gets unexpectedly shut down, the notification should not show. Or am I misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: Hi @LaurensArtapps yes you are right, this will work if you call the method as timer action after the timer ends. But if the local notification is connected to the timer why not to call it after timer ends?

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro You are correct that in the example I've set out this would be a possibility. However, the actual project that I am working on is more complex, with multiple consecutive timers that start running when the previous timer has elapsed. I would rather schedule all the notifications at once than setting 20 timers that run at the same time.

Comment: @LaurensArtapps Ok I understand, sorry but another solution doesn’t come up to my mind.

Comment: @Francesco Deliro Thanks for your time, I think I will implement a resume function when the app starts so that it will be like the app never quit in the first place. That way I can keep the notifications. Have a good day